# goJS disable adding new nodes when no options in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, gojs

I have simple python flask app where I send JSON data to my HTML and with goJS I display my graph which looks like this:

[image]

[image]

I made custom choices dropdown for users to edit node and link text. Those choice options are read from .txt file and sent to html via flask. Options in dropdown lists are made so that when option is selected once, it can not be selected again, until user delete node or link with that used option, and then he can use that option again. So far, I used this code to make nodes text selectable in dropdown list:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>State Chart</title>
<meta name="description" content="A finite state machine chart with editable and interactive features." />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='go.js')}}"></script>

<!-- custom text editors -->
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='TextEditorSelectBox.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='TextEditorRadioButtons.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='TextEditorSelectBox.js')}}"></script>


<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='DataInspector.js')}}"></script>

<link href="https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/DataInspector.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='DataInspector.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script id="code">


    function init() {

        var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
        myDiagram =
        $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",  // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
        {
            // start everything in the middle of the viewport
            initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
            // have mouse wheel events zoom in and out instead of scroll up and down
            "toolManager.mouseWheelBehavior": go.ToolManager.WheelZoom,
            // support double-click in background creating a new node
            "clickCreatingTool.archetypeNodeData": { text: "new node" },
            // enable undo & redo
            "textEditingTool.defaultTextEditor": window.TextEditorSelectBox,
            "undoManager.isEnabled": true,
            "layout": new go.ForceDirectedLayout(),
            "ModelChanged": function(e) {
                console.log("Diagram model changed!");
              if (e.change === go.ChangedEvent.Remove && e.modelChange === "linkDataArray") {
                console.log("eee");
                console.log(e);
                var linkdata = e.oldValue;
                console.log("linkdata");
                console.log(linkdata);
                var oldstr = linkdata.text;
                console.log("oldstr");
                console.log(oldstr);

                if (!oldstr) return;
                var choices = e.model.modelData.choices;
                console.log("choices");
                console.log(choices);
                var idx = choices.indexOf(oldstr);
                if (idx < 0) {
                  console.log("adding choice: " + oldstr);
                  var newchoices = Array.prototype.slice.call(choices);
                  newchoices.push(oldstr);
                  e.model.set(e.model.modelData, "choices", newchoices);
                }
              }
            }
        });

        //myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "choices", JSON.parse('{{ link_choices | tojson | safe}}'));
        //myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "choices", ["one", "two", "three"]);
        console.log("myDiagram.model.modelData");
        console.log(myDiagram.model.modelData);
        console.log("myDiagram.model.modelData.choices");
        console.log(myDiagram.model.modelData.choices);


        // when the document is modified, add a "*" to the title and enable the "Save" button
        myDiagram.addDiagramListener("Modified", function(e) {
            var button = document.getElementById("SaveButton");
            if (button) button.disabled = !myDiagram.isModified;
            var idx = document.title.indexOf("*");
            if (myDiagram.isModified) {
                if (idx < 0) document.title += "*";
            } 
            else {
                if (idx >= 0) document.title = document.title.substr(0, idx);
            }
        });

        myDiagram.addDiagramListener("textEdited", function(e) {
            console.log("Text is edited");
            console.log(e);

            //CHECK IF LINK,
            //IF YES REMOVE THAT OPTION FROM LIST

        });

        myDiagram.addDiagramListener("SelectionDeleting", function(e) {
            console.log("inside SelectionDeleting");
            console.log(e);

            //CHECK IF LINK,
            //IF YES PUT THAT OPTION BACK IN OPTION LIST

        });

            // define the Node template
        myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
          $(go.Node, "Auto",
            new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
            // define the node's outer shape, which will surround the TextBlock
            $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",
              {
                parameter1: 20,  // the corner has a large radius
                fill: $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 0: "rgb(254, 201, 0)", 1: "rgb(254, 162, 0)" }),
                stroke: null,
                portId: "",  // this Shape is the Node's port, not the whole Node
                fromLinkable: true, fromLinkableDuplicates: true,
                toLinkable: true, toLinkableDuplicates: true,
                cursor: "pointer"
              }),
            $(go.TextBlock,
              {
                font: "bold 11pt helvetica, bold arial, sans-serif",
                editable: true,  // editing the text automatically updates the model data
                //textEditor: window.TextEditorRadioButtons, // defined in textEditorRadioButtons.js
                // this specific TextBlock has its own choices:
                textEditor: window.TextEditorRadioButtons,
                //choices: JSON.parse('{{ choices | tojson | safe}}')
                choices: nodeChoices
              },
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        );

        myDiagram.nodeTemplate.selectionAdornmentTemplate =
        $(go.Adornment, "Spot",
            $(go.Panel, "Auto",
            $(go.Shape, { stroke: "dodgerblue", strokeWidth: 2, fill: null }),
            $(go.Placeholder)
        ),
        $(go.Panel, "Horizontal",
            { alignment: go.Spot.Top, alignmentFocus: go.Spot.Bottom },
            $("Button",
                { click: editText },  // defined below, to support editing the text of the node
                $(go.TextBlock, "t",
                { font: "bold 10pt sans-serif", desiredSize: new go.Size(15, 15), textAlign: "center" })
            ),
            $("Button",
            { // drawLink is defined below, to support interactively drawing new links
                click: drawLink,  // click on Button and then click on target node
                actionMove: drawLink  // drag from Button to the target node
            },
            $(go.Shape,
                { geometryString: "M0 0 L8 0 8 12 14 12 M12 10 L14 12 12 14" })
            ),
            $("Button",
            {
                actionMove: dragNewNode,  // defined below, to support dragging from the button
                _dragData: { text: "?????", color: "lightgray" },  // node data to copy
                click: clickNewNode  // defined below, to support a click on the button
            },
            $(go.Shape,
                { geometryString: "M0 0 L3 0 3 10 6 10 x F1 M6 6 L14 6 14 14 6 14z", fill: "gray" })
          )
        )
      );

    //myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "choices", JSON.parse('{{ link_choices | tojson | safe}}'));
    //myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "choices", ["one", "two", "three"]);
    console.log("myDiagram.model.modelData");
    console.log(myDiagram.model.modelData);
    console.log(myDiagram.model.modelData.choices);

    function editText(e, button) {
        //console.log(e);

      var node = button.part.adornedPart;
      console.log("node");
      //console.log(node);
      e.diagram.commandHandler.editTextBlock(node.findObject("TEXTBLOCK"));
      //$("#nodeText").val(node.findObject("TEXTBLOCK"));
    }

    function drawLink(e, button) {
      var node = button.part.adornedPart;
      var tool = e.diagram.toolManager.linkingTool;
      tool.startObject = node.port;
      e.diagram.currentTool = tool;
      tool.doActivate();
    }

   // used by both clickNewNode and dragNewNode to create a node and a link
    // from a given node to the new node
    function createNodeAndLink(data, fromnode) {
        var diagram = fromnode.diagram;
        var model = diagram.model;
        var nodedata = model.copyNodeData(data);
        model.addNodeData(nodedata);
        var newnode = diagram.findNodeForData(nodedata);
        var linkdata = model.copyLinkData({});
        model.setFromKeyForLinkData(linkdata, model.getKeyForNodeData(fromnode.data));
        model.setToKeyForLinkData(linkdata, model.getKeyForNodeData(newnode.data));
        model.addLinkData(linkdata);
        diagram.select(newnode);
        return newnode;
    }

    // the Button.click event handler, called when the user clicks the "N" button
    function clickNewNode(e, button) {
        var data = button._dragData;
        if (!data) return;
        e.diagram.startTransaction("Create Node and Link");
        var fromnode = button.part.adornedPart;
        var newnode = createNodeAndLink(button._dragData, fromnode);
        newnode.location = new go.Point(fromnode.location.x + 200, fromnode.location.y);
        e.diagram.commitTransaction("Create Node and Link");
    }

    // the Button.actionMove event handler, called when the user drags within the "N" button
    function dragNewNode(e, button) {
        var tool = e.diagram.toolManager.draggingTool;
        if (tool.isBeyondDragSize()) {
            var data = button._dragData;
            if (!data) return;
            e.diagram.startTransaction("button drag");  // see doDeactivate, below
            var newnode = createNodeAndLink(data, button.part.adornedPart);
            newnode.location = e.diagram.lastInput.documentPoint;
            // don't commitTransaction here, but in tool.doDeactivate, after drag operation finished
            // set tool.currentPart to a selected movable Part and then activate the DraggingTool
            tool.currentPart = newnode;
            e.diagram.currentTool = tool;
            tool.doActivate();
        }
    }

    // using dragNewNode also requires modifying the standard DraggingTool so that it
    // only calls commitTransaction when dragNewNode started a "button drag" transaction;
    // do this by overriding DraggingTool.doDeactivate:
    var tool = myDiagram.toolManager.draggingTool;
    tool.doDeactivate = function() {
        // commit "button drag" transaction, if it is ongoing; see dragNewNode, above
        if (tool.diagram.undoManager.nestedTransactionNames.elt(0) === "button drag") {
            tool.diagram.commitTransaction();
        }
        go.DraggingTool.prototype.doDeactivate.call(tool);  // call the base method
    };

    // replace the default Link template in the linkTemplateMap
    myDiagram.linkTemplate =
        $(go.Link,  // the whole link panel
        {
            curve: go.Link.Bezier, 
            adjusting: go.Link.Stretch,
            reshapable: true, 
            relinkableFrom: true, 
            relinkableTo: true,
            toShortLength: 3
        },
        new go.Binding("points").makeTwoWay(),
        new go.Binding("curviness"),
        $(go.Shape,  // the link shape
            { strokeWidth: 1.5 }),
        $(go.Shape,  // the arrowhead
            { toArrow: "standard", stroke: null }),
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
            $(go.Shape,  // the label background, which becomes transparent around the edges
            {
                fill: $(go.Brush, "Radial", { 0: "rgb(240, 240, 240)", 0.3: "rgb(240, 240, 240)", 1: "rgba(240, 240, 240, 0)" }),
                stroke: null
            }),
            $(go.TextBlock,
              {
                background: "white",
                editable: true,
                textEditor: window.TextEditorSelectBox, // defined in extensions/textEditorSelectBox.js
                textEdited: function(tb, oldstr, newstr) {
                  var choices = tb.diagram.model.modelData.choices;
                  console.log("choices");
                  console.log(choices);
                  console.log("newstr");
                  console.log(newstr);
                  console.log("oldstr");
                  console.log(oldstr);
                  var idx = choices.indexOf(newstr);
                  if (idx >= 0 && oldstr !== newstr) {
                    console.log(choices);
                    console.log("choices");
                    console.log(choices);
                    console.log("removing choice " + idx + ": " + newstr);
                    var newchoices = Array.prototype.slice.call(choices);
                    newchoices.splice(idx, 1);
                    tb.diagram.model.set(tb.diagram.model.modelData, "choices", newchoices);
                    tb.editable = false;  // don't allow choice again
                  }
                }
              },
            // editing the text automatically updates the model data
            //new go.Binding("text"),
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay(),
            new go.Binding("choices").ofModel())
        )
    );


    var inspector = new Inspector('myInspectorDiv', myDiagram,
    {
        // uncomment this line to only inspect the named properties below instead of all properties on each object:
        // includesOwnProperties: false,
        properties: {
            "text": { },
            // an example of specifying the type
            "password": { show: Inspector.showIfPresent, type: 'password' },
            // key would be automatically added for nodes, but we want to declare it read-only also:
            "key": { readOnly: true, show: Inspector.showIfPresent },
            // color would be automatically added for nodes, but we want to declare it a color also:
            "color": { show: Inspector.showIfPresent, type: 'color' },
            // Comments and LinkComments are not in any node or link data (yet), so we add them here:
            "Comments": { show: Inspector.showIfNode  },
            "flag": { show: Inspector.showIfNode, type: 'checkbox' },
            "LinkComments": { show: Inspector.showIfLink },
            "isGroup": { readOnly: true, show: Inspector.showIfPresent }
        }
    });

    // read in the JSON data from flask
    loadGraphData();

    }

    function loadGraphData() {
        var graphDataString = JSON.parse('{{ diagramData | tojson | safe}}');
        //console.log("graphDataString");
        //console.log(graphDataString);

        myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(graphDataString);
        //myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "choices", ["one", "two", "three"]);
        myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "choices", JSON.parse('{{ link_choices | tojson | safe}}'));
        console.log("whole model");
        console.log(myDiagram.model);
    }

    function saveGraphData(form, event) {
        console.log("inside saveGraphData");
        event.preventDefault();

        document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value = myDiagram.model.toJson();
        form.submit();
    }

    function zoomToFit(){
        console.log("inside zoomToFit");
        myDiagram.zoomToRect(myDiagram.documentBounds);
    }

    function zoomIn(){
        console.log("inside zoomIn");
        myDiagram.commandHandler.increaseZoom();
    }
    function zoomOut(){
        console.log("inside zoomOut");
        myDiagram.commandHandler.decreaseZoom();
    }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

    <div id=formWrapper style="padding: 30px;">

        <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:5000/updateResultFile" name="updateResultFileForm" 
        id="updateResultFileForm" 
        onsubmit="saveGraphData(this, event);">

            <div id="graphWrapper" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; width: 100%; height: 800px;margin-bottom: 15px;"></div>
                <div style="display: none;"><input id="mySavedModel" name="mySavedModel"></div>

                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"> Save <i class="fa fa-save"> </i> </button>

            </div>

        </form>

        <div id="myInspectorDiv">
        </div>

        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="zoomToFit()"> Zoom to fit  <i class="fa fa-search"> </i> </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="zoomIn()"> Zoom in  <i class="fa fa-search-plus"> </i> </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="zoomOut()"> Zoom out  <i class="fa fa-search-minus"> </i> </button>
        </div>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to make when the user used all options for links and none of them is available to use, I would like to disable availability to add a new link. Also if he uses all options for node texts, I would like to disable the possibility to add new nodes. But, if the user deletes some node and that option for node text is free again, I would like to enable him the possibility to add new nodes with that option but I don't have any idea how to make diagram disable his core part to add new nodes or links?

Also, it is somehow hard to make double click on link text to make dropdown with options appear. Is there any trick or option to make it easier to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize you had asked this so many times.

```
function init() {
  var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

  myDiagram =
    $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
      {
        initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
        "undoManager.isEnabled": true,
        "ModelChanged": function(e) {     // just for demonstration purposes,
          if (e.isTransactionFinished) {  // show the model data in the page's TextArea
            document.getElementById("mySavedModel").textContent = e.model.toJson();
          }
          if (e.change === go.ChangedEvent.Remove) {
            if (e.modelChange === "linkDataArray") {
              var linkdata = e.oldValue;
              var oldstr = linkdata.text;
              if (!oldstr) return;
              var linkchoices = e.model.modelData.linkchoices;
              var idx = linkchoices.indexOf(oldstr);
              if (idx < 0) {
                console.log("deletion adding link choice: " + oldstr);
                var newlinkchoices = Array.prototype.slice.call(linkchoices);
                newlinkchoices.push(oldstr);
                e.model.set(e.model.modelData, "linkchoices", newlinkchoices);
              }
            } else if (e.modelChange === "nodeDataArray") {
              var nodedata = e.oldValue;
              var oldstr = nodedata.text;
              if (!oldstr) return;
              var nodechoices = e.model.modelData.nodechoices;
              var idx = nodechoices.indexOf(oldstr);
              if (idx < 0) {
                console.log("deletion adding node choice: " + oldstr);
                var newnodechoices = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodechoices);
                newnodechoices.push(oldstr);
                e.model.set(e.model.modelData, "nodechoices", newnodechoices);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });

  myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
    $(go.Node, "Auto",
      $(go.Shape,
        { fill: "white", portId: "", fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true, cursor: "pointer" },
        new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
      $(go.TextBlock,
        {
          margin: 8,
          editable: true,
          textEditor: window.TextEditorSelectBox, // defined in extensions/textEditorSelectBox.js
          textEdited: function(tb, oldstr, newstr) {
            if (oldstr !== newstr) {
              console.log("changing from " + oldstr + " to " + newstr);
              var model = tb.diagram.model;
              var nodechoices = model.modelData.nodechoices;
              if (!nodechoices) {
                nodechoices = [];
                model.set(model.modelData, "nodechoices", nodechoices);
              }
              var idx = nodechoices.indexOf(newstr);
              if (idx >= 0) {
                console.log("removing node choice " + idx + ": " + newstr);
                model.removeArrayItem(nodechoices, idx);
              }
              if (oldstr) {
                console.log("  adding node choice " + oldstr);
                model.addArrayItem(nodechoices, oldstr);
              }
            }
          }
        },
        new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay(),
        new go.Binding("choices", "nodechoices").ofModel())
    );

  myDiagram.linkTemplate =
    $(go.Link,
      $(go.Shape),
      $(go.Shape, { toArrow: "OpenTriangle" }),
      $(go.TextBlock,
        {
          background: "white",
          editable: true,
          textEditor: window.TextEditorSelectBox, // defined in extensions/textEditorSelectBox.js
          textEdited: function(tb, oldstr, newstr) {
            if (oldstr !== newstr) {
              console.log("changing from " + oldstr + " to " + newstr);
              var model = tb.diagram.model;
              var linkchoices = model.modelData.linkchoices;
              if (!linkchoices) {
                linkchoices = [];
                model.set(model.modelData, "linkchoices", linkchoices);
              }
              var idx = linkchoices.indexOf(newstr);
              if (idx >= 0) {
                console.log("removing link choice " + idx + ": " + newstr);
                model.removeArrayItem(linkchoices, idx);
              }
              if (oldstr) {
                console.log("  adding link choice " + oldstr);
                model.addArrayItem(linkchoices, oldstr);
              }
            }
          }
        },
        new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay(),
        new go.Binding("choices", "linkchoices").ofModel())
    );

  myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
  [
    { key: 1, text: "Alpha", color: "lightblue" },
    { key: 2, text: "Beta", color: "orange" },
    { key: 3, text: "Gamma", color: "lightgreen" },
    { key: 4, text: "Delta", color: "pink" }
  ],
  [
    { from: 1, to: 2, text: "one" },
    { from: 1, to: 3, text: "two" },
    { from: 3, to: 4, text: "three" }
  ]);
  myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "nodechoices", ["Epsilon"]);
  myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "linkchoices", ["four"]);
}
```